# check last n elements are equal in numpy array python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, iterator

I have a numpy array with numbers, and I want to count how many elements are equal starting from the last element.

```
A = [1, 3, 2, 2, 0, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2]
```

then I want the return value to be 4 (last four elements are equal)

Comment: Why not a simple for loop?

Comment: Do you mean equal or consecutive?

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on his own. A good way to show this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: 'B = [1, 3, 2, 2, 0, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2]' should return value 2 (last two elements are equal).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For large arrays where you expect only a few items to be identical, a generator expression with `next` may be efficient:

```
A = np.array([1, 3, 2, 2, 0, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2])

last = A[-1]
res = next(i for i, j in enumerate(A[::-1]) if j != last)
# 4
```

Answer (score 4):

```
print(np.argmax(A[::-1] != A[-1]))
```

I'm not sure about how this performs when A is super large. In that case, simple for loop would be better.

Note : Why this works can be understood with the following line in the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html):

> In case of multiple occurrences of the maximum values, the indices corresponding to the first occurrence are returned.

---

Thanks YSelf for correction.